# WPF Media Element Slider Status

Tags: wpf, video-streaming, win-universal-app, mediaelement

When streaming a video from internet url WPF MediaElement is waiting sometimes to buffer video. In this case I can see that MediaElement Status change.

If we use a slider then we can see the current position of video but I want to see a different status which has just downloaded from the url. For example Youtube videos has 2 status, first is current position and the second is buffered lenght.

How can we apply that for WPF if not possible Universal app is second option for platform

Answer (score 0):

The MediaElement in WPF currently doesn't support this. There is no way to get the buffered bytes or time.